# run npm script command with argument

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

Suppose I have an npm script, specified in my packages.json with the following form:

```json
"scripts": {
    "publish": "npm publish && git push",
}
```

I want to pass an argument to `npm publish` (e.g. `--otp=12345`), but if I try `npm run publish --<arg>`, won't this pass the argument to the `git push` rather than the previous command? If so, how do I direct an argument from the calling command to the appropriate subcommand?